# trying to extract phone number from a resume

Tags: nltk, findall

When I try to use the `findall` function I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'findall'
```

here is my code :

```
def phone(content):
    content.findall(r"<.*><phone><.*><.*><.*>")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to use a regular expression? In this case, the syntax is `re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)`, thus `re.findall("<.*><phone><.*><.*><.*>", content)` in your case. See the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). Note that this returns a list, and you can access results by indexing with `[x]`.